# Way to achieve overlapping GROUP BY groups with correct subtotals in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

Assuming following schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test
(
    date Date, 
    user_id UInt32,
    user_answer UInt8,
    user_multi_choice_answer Array(UInt8),
    events UInt32
)
ENGINE = MergeTree() ORDER BY date;
```

And contents:

```sql
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ('2020-01-01', 1, 5, [2, 3], 15),
  ('2020-01-01', 2, 6, [1, 2], 7);
```

Let's say I want to make a query "give me # of users and # of their events grouped by date and user_answer, with subtotals". That's easy:

```sql
select date, user_answer, count(distinct user_id), sum(events) from test group by date, user_answer with rollup;
┌───────date─┬─user_answer─┬─uniqExact(user_id)─┬─sum(events)─┐
│ 2020-01-01 │           5 │                  1 │          15 │
│ 2020-01-01 │           6 │                  1 │           7 │
│ 2020-01-01 │           0 │                  2 │          22 │
│ 0000-00-00 │           0 │                  2 │          22 │
└────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

What I can't easily do is making queries with overlapping groups, like when grouping by invidivual options of multiple choice question. For example:

- # of users and # of their events grouped by date and user_multi_choice_answer, with subtotals
- # of users and # of their events grouped by arbitrary hand-written grouping conditions, like "compare users with user_answer=5 and has(user_multi_choice_answer, 1) to users with has(user_multi_choice_answer, 2)"

For example, with the first query, I would like to see the following:

```sql
┌───────date─┬─user_multi_choice_answer─┬─uniqExact(user_id)─┬─sum(events)─┐
│ 2020-01-01 │                        1 │                  1 │          15 │
│ 2020-01-01 │                        2 │                  2 │          22 │
│ 2020-01-01 │                        3 │                  1 │           7 │
│ 2020-01-01 │                        0 │                  2 │          22 │
│ 0000-00-00 │                        0 │                  2 │          22 │
└────────────┴──────────────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

And for the second:

```sql
┌─my_grouping_id─┬─uniqExact(user_id)─┬─sum(events)─┐
│              1 │                  1 │          15 │ # users fulfilling arbitrary condition #1
│              2 │                  2 │          22 │ # users fulfilling arbitrary condition #2
│              0 │                  2 │          22 │ # subtotal
└────────────────┴────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

The closest I can get to that is by using `arrayJoin()`:

```sql
select date, arrayJoin(user_multi_choice_answer) as multi_answer, count(distinct user_id), sum(events)
from test group by date, multi_answer with rollup;

select arrayJoin(
  arrayConcat(
    if(user_answer=5 and has(user_multi_choice_answer, 3), [1], []),
    if(has(user_multi_choice_answer, 2), [2], [])
  )
) as my_grouping_id, count(distinct user_id), sum(events)
from test group by my_grouping_id with rollup;
```

But that's not a good solution for two reasons:

- While it calculates correct results for grouping, the result for `sum(events)` is not correct for subtotals (as duplicated rows count multiple times)
- It doesn't seem efficient, as it makes a lot of data duplication (while I just want the same row to get aggregated into several groups)

So, again, I'm looking for a way that would allow me to easily make grouping of answers to multiple choice questions and gropings by arbitrary conditions on some columns. I'm okay with changing the schema to make that possible, but I'm mostly hoping Clickhouse has a built-in way to achieve that.

Comment: just remark: "the result for sum(events) is not correct for subtotals" - rollup works correctly as required. As a workaround, you can use direct-query to calculate each sub-group: *select  date, arrayJoin(user_multi_choice_answer) as multi_answer, count(distinct user_id) as uniq_users, sum(events) sum from test group by date, multi_answer union all select date, 0 as multi_answer, count(distinct user_id) as uniq_users, sum(events) as sum from test group by date;*

Comment: Just raw-suggestions: 1) consider flattening the original table - instead of *user_multi_choice_answer Array(UInt8)* use *UInt8 choise_answer*. It leads to a significant increase in row count and probably gets some performance benefits. 2) if 'arbitrary'-queries can be formalized then consider using the extra table with [AggregatingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/aggregatingmergetree/)-engine in which be stored pre-calculated intermediate results.

Comment: "Rollup works correctly as required" I know, just bad wording on my side. Result is correct, just not the one I need in the end. "You can use direct-query to calculate each sub-group" I could, but it doesn't scale if I want to `group by` by more than just date and a single answer column.

Comment: As for the raw-suggestions: my real table has unfortunately more columns, some of which are also "multiple choice", so flattening isn't really feasible (unless I separate that data into a separate smaller per-user table and join it, but that brings different issues).

Answer (score 0):

> While it calculates correct results for grouping, the result for sum(events) is not correct for subtotals (as duplicated rows count multiple times)

You can manually create `my_grouping_id = 0` without using rollup. For example,

```sql
select arrayJoin(
  arrayConcat(
    [0],
    if(user_answer=5 and has(user_multi_choice_answer, 3), [1], []),
    if(has(user_multi_choice_answer, 2), [2], [])
  )
) as my_grouping_id, count(distinct user_id), sum(events)
from test group by my_grouping_id
```

> It doesn't seem efficient, as it makes a lot of data duplication (while I just want the same row to get aggregated into several groups)

Currently it's not possible. But I see possibilities. I'll try to make a POC of `GROUP BY ARRAY`. It seems to be a valid use case.

Comment: "You can manually create my_grouping_id = 0 without using rollup" you're right, I didn't think about that. That solves some of my current issues, but long-term that still doesn't compose well (as I want to group by more columns like date and still have access to rollup). `GROUP BY ARRAY` also sounds great; I imagine it'd make mixing "normal" and "array" columns a bit awkward (`GROUP BY ARRAY [a], b, [c], d`?), but that's probably not a big deal (or could be solved by different syntax).